# How to write JavaScript Integration Tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, jasmine-jquery

I must write Integration Tests for a RequireJS application. I have never done that before and I don't find any examples on the Internet. Why is there that few information about that subject? I read many descriptions what Integration Tests are but I am still not sure how to write them. I have no server or db code for my application, this means I can only test the collaboration of the different modules, right? I already tried to write some tests with Jasmine, e.g. when `render()` is called in Module1, Module2 is instanciated and `Module2.render()` is called, too. `Module2.render()` should add some html code. Thus I used jasmine-jquery.js to test whether the html code was added: `expect($('#test1')).toExist();`

Is this an Integration Test? Or would this rather be added to Unit Tests?

I am also not sure, if I can write Integration Tests with Nightwatch.js and if this would be reasonable. I am now writing System Tests with this Framework, but it seems to be a bit like integration testing, because I am testing, if the components work together. When is a Nightwatch test called Integration Test and when is it called System Test?

Comment: From my experience writing unit and integration tests and seeing them both confused on numerous occasions. I like to employ the following rule: **A unit test tests a single piece of functionality**, such as a public function; **An integration test tests multiple pieces of functionality that should interact in a defined way together**. The important thing really is to be in control of the input and know the expected output in both cases, no matter the definition of the test.

Comment: @JeremyBrooks definition is quite good, according to International Software Testing Qualifications Board (ISTQ) syllabus : http://www.istqb.org/downloads/syllabi/foundation-level-syllabus.html

Answer (score 2):

i would say that 'integration' test should check how does your js code 'integrate' with rest of the application. that is if it sends and receives correct messages to/from backend, if it communicates correctly with browser storage etc. What you describe looks like a unit test

i don't know nightwatch but according to their page

> Nightwatch.js is an easy to use Node.js based End-to-End (E2E) testing solution for browser based apps and websites

it should get the job done

Comment: would it be an integration test, if i use a fake server that always responds with the same message and test if a function calls a callback function after successful server request?